# Using noexec option in fstab

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

[This link](https://superuser.com/questions/728127/what-does-noexec-flag-mean-when-mounting-directories-on-rhel) explains the benefits of using `noexec` option when using `mount`. However it lists one limitation - if I have a Perl/Python/shell script or a file that starts with `#!` and will try to execute it - I will be able to do so whether I supplied the option or not.

Is there a way to prevent such execution? I.e. is there an additional option to `noexec` which I can give and the execution of the scripts will not be possible?

Comment: "and will try to execute it" How? By running it directly or by passing it to the interpreter?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, both ways. I can try to click the script, or I can just type it in the terminal.

Comment: Neither of those ways answers my question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, well, then I guess I don't understand the question. Could you please clarify? Because I presumed by second you meant just typing `cd <noexec_mounted_partition> && python my_script.py`.

Comment: That is the second, yes. And that will not execute it so `noexec` won't affect it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, OK, I guess I misunderstood the answer that question. But lets say I have a script that do `cat /etc/passwd`. Then when I try to run it it will print the content of that file to the stdout, right? And sorry for misinterpreting that answer.

Comment: That depends on how you "run" it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, the second way. See my answer above. Just presume I do `cd <noexec_mount_partition> && python my_script.py` and the script will print /etc/passwd file. I am not very familiar with python so can't put this script on. Or just imagine I have a bash script.

Comment: Passing it to the interpreter doesn't execute the script, it only reads it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, so thats what `noexec` will do in this case? It will just print `cat /etc/passwd`, but not the actual file? Also what is the first way you were asking in the first reply?

Comment: `noexec` will do nothing. The interpreter will read the script and do whatever the script tells it to.

Comment: The first way is running `path/to/script.py`. This *will* execute the script, if possible.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, so the content of the file /etc/passwd will be printed in that case? I don't want that and would like to avoid that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, but the first way will be prevented by `noexec`.

Comment: `noexec` will prevent the script from being executed, but not read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69089/discussion-between-igor-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I don't care about reading for now, at least. I just need to prevent executing the binary and the script. So if I run the script with `python test_script.py` as in the sample above will it print the content of the script or the content of /etc/passwd?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It turned out (in my opinion) there was more beneath the surface. Check my answer, you may find it interesting.

Answer (score 12):

There's a major misunderstanding here. Let's make these things clear.

First of all, [the limitation](https://superuser.com/a/728129/432690) you refer to, as it is stated, **is not true**:

> However, when a script (a text file that begins with she-bang line; i.e., a line that begins with `#!`) is given to some shells (bash), it will run the executable named on that line (e.g., `/usr/bin/perl`) and connect the content of the script file to the stdin of that executable, which may not be on that drive.

Surprisingly it seems to explain [the ability to execute, despite `noexec`](https://superuser.com/q/728127/432690). I think the asker there got it all wrong in the first place and it wasn't his or her fault! One wrong assumption in the question caused another wrong assumption in the answer.

What's wrong then?

#### 1. Bind mount is specific

To get some context let's see what happens when you try to bind mount as read-only. There's this question: [*Why doesn't mount respect the read only option for bind mounts?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128336/108618) The conclusion is:

> To achieve the desired result one needs to run two commands:
>
> ```
> mount SRC DST -o bind
> mount DST -o remount,ro,bind
> ```
>
> Newer versions of mount (util-linux >=2.27) do this automatically when one runs
>
> ```
> mount SRC DST -o bind,ro
> ```

But when you try to use `noexec` instead of `ro`, you still need two commands! In my Kubuntu I have `util-linux 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3` and this command:

```
mount SRC DST -o bind,noexec
```

ignores `noexec`, I need to remount. It's the same if mounting is via `/etc/fstab`. You can experiment. At any time check with plain `mount` command what the actual options are.

I bet the asker thought the mount was with `noexec` option, but actually it was not. He or she was able to execute a script from within allegedly `noexec` mountpoint. It was strange, hence the question.

Then the answer author interpreted this, as if it was the shell what reads shebang, calls another executable and doesn't worry about `noexec` for the script. If the mountpoint was really `noexec` then this would be a reasonable speculation.

But…

#### 2. It's a common myth that shells read shebangs; kernel does

Read [*How does the #! shebang work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3009192) and notice one of the answers there had originally followed the myth, then it was corrected.

So if you have:

- a mountpoint `/mnt/foo/` with `noexec` option,
- a script `/mnt/foo/script.py` which is otherwise executable (e.g. `chmod -x …` was invoked),
- a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line in the script

and you run it like this

```
/mnt/foo/script.py
```

then your Linux kernel won't let you because of `noexec`. It would have happened in this other question if the mounting was actually `noexec` there; but I believe it was not.

#### 3. Still, there are two ways to "execute" a script

From comments:

> "and will try to execute it" How? By running it directly or by passing it to the interpreter?

Running it directly means:

```
 /mnt/foo/script.py
```

This will honor `noexec` as elaborated above. The executable *is* `script.py`.

Passing it to the interpreter means:

```
python /mnt/foo/script.py
```

In this case the executable is `python`. It doesn't matter if `foo/` is mounted with `noexec`; it doesn't matter if `script.py` is executable at all; it doesn't matter what the shebang is. The point is `script.py` is not executed, it's *read*.

As long as user can read a file and run proper interpreter, there's no way to prevent passing the file to the interpreter; but it's not the file that is executed.

Comment: thank you for such a complete and perfectly put explanation. Duly noted.