# mount binded partition with noexec

Tags: linux, mount

I had a long conversation about the "noexec" mount option [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1270608/using-noexec-option-in-fstab?noredirect=1#comment1872805_1270608).

Unfortunately it looks like all this moot. The problem is that I am trying to add the "noexec" option to the "bind"-ed mountpoint. Something like this:

```
/bin/tmp   /tmp   none   defaults,bind,noexec 0 0
```

Adding "noexec" option as in the code above does not prevent a person to do, for example, `cd /temp && cp /bin/cp ./ && cp`.

So now the question is - is it possible to either make "noexec" working like this or do something else in order no to allow people to run program from (as in the example above) /tmp?

Thank you.

Comment: @davidgo solution will work, but I found another solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/359530/make-home-tmp-noexec-nodev-without-a-separate-patition).

Comment: While you were writing this comment I was testing a theory and got side-tracked - I don't think mounting noexec will help - I tried a script, which would not run directly, but which I could bypass with /bin/bash /noexecedmount/script.name

Comment: @davidgo, that's a limitatgion of the `noexec` mount option. But the binary will not be executed. And IA will be able to run their scripts on the machine from /tmp as they have scripts they need to run from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent people running a program from /tmp you would need to use something like [Apparmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor), or more commonly [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux).  Depending on your users access (ie what applications they use) , you may find it easier to dump them in a chroot jail or, if its PHP, modify php.ini to prevent executing files from certain locations and calling shells.

Comment: I already have SELinux. But thank you for other solutions as well.